# How to create gradle task which always runs?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm likely overlooking something pretty core/obvious, but how can I create a task that will always be executed for every task/target?

I can do something like:

```
task someTask << {
    println "I sometimes run"
}
println "I always run"
```

But it would be much more desirable to have the always running part in a task.

The closest I've come is:

```
task someTask << {
    println "I sometimes run"
}

println "I always run"

void helloThing() {
    println "I always run too. Hello?"
}

helloThing()
```

So, using a method is an 'ok' solution, but I was hoping there'd be a way to specifically designate/re-use a task.

Hopefully somebody has a way to do this. :)

Comment: If there are N tasks, this function should be called N times, right? What if some tasks are NEVER executed in the given build?

Comment: Or do you want a function to be called for every project?

Comment: Once per build.  No matter which tasks are invoked.

Comment: It's an unusual requirement, and there is no first-class feature for that. What's the use case?

Comment: I guess the thought was a more organizational approach to common build 'tasks'...but I might just resort to using methods for some of those cases.

Comment: One particular case, was for diagnostic/system status information.  Which, in some cases I'd just want to invoke the task 'systemStatus', but I'd also want that information to spit out for every build too. (of course I could accomplish something similar with methods under the hood...but just thought their might be a common way to do it with tasks).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the goal is to print system information, you could either just always print the information in the configuration phase (outside a task declaration), and have a dummy task `systemStatus` that does nothing (because the information is printed anyway). Or you could implement it as a regular task, and make sure the task always gets run by adding `":systemStatus"` as the first item of `gradle.startParameter.taskNames` (a list of strings), which simulates someone always typing `gradle :systemStatus ...`. Or you could leverage a hook such as `gradle.projectsLoaded { ... }` to print the information there.

Comment: That's a cool trick about dynamically manipulating the taskNames list. (for reference, this works: "gradle.startParameter.taskNames = [":someTask"] + gradle.startParameter.taskNames")

Comment: Any idea how to 'hook' a task to another task, other than with 'execute' which is discouraged?

Comment: `dependsOn` or `finalizedBy`.

Answer (score 8):

This attaches a closure to every task in every project in the given build:

```
def someClosure = { task ->
  println "task executed: $task"
}

allprojects {
  afterEvaluate {
    for(def task in it.tasks)
      task << someClosure
  }
}
```

If you need the function/closure to be called only once per build, **before** all tasks of all projects, use this:

```
task('MyTask') << {
  println 'Pre-build hook!'
}

allprojects {
  afterEvaluate {
    for(def task in it.tasks)
      if(task != rootProject.tasks.MyTask)
        task.dependsOn rootProject.tasks.MyTask
  }
}
```

If you need the function/closure to be called only once per build, **after** all tasks of all projects, use this:

```
task('MyTask') << {
  println 'Post-build hook!'
}

allprojects {
  afterEvaluate {
    for(def task in it.tasks)
      if(task != rootProject.tasks.MyTask)
        task.finalizedBy rootProject.tasks.MyTask
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm...that is pretty handy...a little more verbose than I was hoping, but still pretty easy.

Comment: I updated my answer, caring for what you said - "Once per build".

Comment: It's better to use a per-build hook than a per-project hook. The second snippet will run the task at the end of the build, rather than the start.

Comment: I picked Peter's answer cause it is a little more succinct.  That said, I might use this other approach too.  (but I can only pick one answer ;)).  Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Good point, Peter, thank you. I extended the answer with two variants: pre-build and post-build hook.

Comment: It's a pleasure to participate in such discussions, the one learns a lot :)

Comment: It just dawned on me, that there is one (potentially important) difference between the solution from @PeterNiederwieser and from me: Peter's variant will be ALWAYS called, independently on the execution of other tasks. My variant (post-hook and pre-hook) will be called ONLY THEN, when at least one other task was executed (directly or as a dependency). For example, if all tasks up-to-date, then hooks are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with invoking it straight from the root `build.gradle`?

```groovy
task init << {
    println "I always run"
}

tasks.init.execute()
```

Comment: execute() is now a deprecated feature and will be removed in Gradle 5.0