# How to use gradle extension correctly in plugins using GradleBuild task?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

**EDIT** : I rephrased my question in taken the propositon of David M. Karr into account.

I am writing a gradle plugin. This plugin is launching a task extending GradleBuild. The external gradle build file needs some info as parameters. These parameters are given in project extension.

Plugin code

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    def mExt

    void apply(Project project) {

        mExt = project.extensions.create('myext',MyExt)

        project.task('myTask', type:GradleBuild){
            def param = new StartParameter()
            param.setProjectProperties([target:getTarget()])

            // Problem here
            startParameter = param
            buildFile = getMyBuildPath()
            tasks = [
                'build',
                'generateDebugJavadocJar'
            ]
        }
    }

    def getMyBuildPath(){
        ...
    }

    // Problem here
    def getTarget(){
        return {mExt.target}
    }
}

class MyExt {
    def String target = "uninitialised"
}
```

Gradle build file :

```
apply plugin : 'com.example.myplugin'

ext{
    target = "myTarget"
}
```

External Gradle build file :

```
task build(){
    println project.target
}
```

If I put a closure in `getTarget()`, `println project.target` shows the closure and not the string.

If I don't put the closure :

```
     // Problem here
    def getTarget(){
        return mExt.target
    }
```

Then I got "uninitialised" instead of "myTarget".

How can I get the value of myext.target here ?

I am using gradle 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded in getting what I wanted to in using project.afterEvaluate method. [Thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682676/how-can-i-make-gradle-extensions-lazily-evaluate-properties-that-are-set-dynamic?rq=1)

1) In gradle build task, `startParameter.projectProperties` is waiting for a map, not a closure. So the idea to put a closure for a lazy definition cannot work.

2) If I put directly in my plugin a reference to `mExt.target` or `project.myext.target`, then the initial value is set. The value put in my build.gradle file is not used because the plugin is already evaluated.

3) `project.afterEvaluate()` solve my problem. The closure ends configuring myTask in using the project's extension.

```
void apply(Project project) {

    project.extensions.create('myext',MyExt)

    project.task('myTask', type:GradleBuild){
        buildFile = getMyBuildPath()
        tasks = [
            'build',
            'generateDebugJavadocJar'
        ]
    }

    project.afterEvaluate { proj ->
        proj.myTask.startParameter.projectProperties = [target:proj.myext.target]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Define an instance variable called "myext", of type "MyExt".

In the "apply" method, do this:

```
myext = project.extensions.create('myext',MyExt)
```

In the "getTarget" method, return "myext.target".

Comment: The problem here is that the value configured in root gradle build is not taken into account.  If I do `param.setProjectProperties([target:myext.target])`, the initial value of target is used, but not the one specified in the build file using the plugin. And I cannot use a closure that would solve my problem. Any other idea ?