# Configure gradle projects in SonarQube

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, liferay, sonarqube-scan

I am working with Liferay DXP and I would like integrate SonarQube in my workspace, I am using gradle.

My workspace is called: test-workpace

My gradle.properies file (path: test-workspace/gradle.properties) is:

```
systemProp.sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
systemProp.sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
systemProp.sonar.forceAuthentication=true
systemProp.sonar.login=<mytoken>

# Definición de variables para el proyecto.
description = 'Gradle - Sample Project'
group = 'com.test.sonarqube.gradle'
version = '1.0.0'
```

My build.gradle file (path: test-workspace/build.gradle) is:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
                mavenLocal()
                jcenter()
                maven {
                        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
                }
        }
        dependencies {
                classpath group: "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle", name:"sonarqube-gradle-plugin", version:"2.5"
        }
}

group = 'com.test.sonarqube.gradle'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

When I execute "gradle sonarqube" all workspace is scanned but  I would like to configure each modules like a project in SonarQube.

Someone know how to configure gradle files to do it?.

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Answer (score 0):

As Olaf points out: This question was also posted to https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/104477676

You could configure all the subprojects as a different SonarQube project with the following in your `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects{
  sonarqube {
      properties {
          property 'sonar.projectName', "${-> project.name}"
      }
  }
}
```

You can also set the property `sonar.projectKey` or any other property from https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

I took the idea of the lazily evaluated project name from: [How can I make Gradle extensions lazily evaluate properties that are set dynamically by tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682676/how-can-i-make-gradle-extensions-lazily-evaluate-properties-that-are-set-dynamic)